# How to display different components in one route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How to display different components in one route?

I have a route config in which I form routes and components for them, but there are some routes that return the same component, but they have a different path, because of this I get errors

Is it possible somehow to use one route instead of two, in order to render the component once?

```
  {
    path: '/users', // if no user is selected
    breadcrumb: 'Title',
    sidebarTitle: 'Users',
    exact: true,
    sidebar: () => <Sidebar component={<List.UserList/>} />, // 1
    main: () => <Modules.UserBlank/>,
  },
  {
    path: '/users/:id/:name', // if user is selected
    sidebarTitle: 'Users',
    exact: true,
    breadcrumb: DynamicBreadcrumb,
    sidebar: () => <Sidebar component={<List.UserList/>} />, // 2
    main: () => <Modules.User/>,
  },
```

Comment: Two different routes should certainly be able to render the same component. What are the errors? Can you also update the question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for how these routes are rendered?

Comment: index.js:1 Warning: Cannot update a component (`SidebarBreadcrumps`) while rendering a different component (`Unknown`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Unknown`, follow the stack trace as described i

Comment: What is `SidebarBreadcrumps` component? Can you edit your question to include all relevant code you are working with? We should be able to have enough context to reproduce the issue.